# Mutli Schools SQL Diagram

Tags: mysql, sql, diagram

I have to make a multiple school manager, so this is what my script has to do:

- List of all schools
- List of all students from a specific school
- List of parents from a specific student
- Add student / parent / school
- Edit sutdent / parent / school
- Remove student / parent / school

This is my Diagram: (cannot post image directly)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dga52.png

What do you think? Is it correct? I think something is missing...

Answer (score 0):

Well it will do the job, untill reality kicks in. Students and staff change schools so you probably want to account for that somewhere. This will soon devolve into many-to-many relationships so join tables will be neccessary. These would then contain the start and end dates of the assocciation. You should also consider that the parents and pupils probably share the same address so an addresses table makes more sense, especialy when they change address and several records will need to be updated.

Comment: I agree with u for everything but the parents address because sometime parents are divorced and does'nt have the same adress. I am working on the associations but still wondering why do I need it... Does a student associate to multiple school?

Comment: The addresses table would enable that as each person would have a foreign key to an address and that can be different for each parent. Where the student lives is another matter :) Yes, students associate to diferent schools, sometimes at the same time. Either way, you need a start date and end date because studenst leave school eventualy. Same with staff.